# Shadow DOM with Python Selenium Geckodriver

Tags: selenium, firefox, web-scraping, geckodriver, shadow-dom

I am trying this code to access a shadow root element on the following website https://www.wego.ae/en/flights/searches/cSFO-cLHR-2020-03-09:cLHR-cSFO-2020-03-22/economy/1a:0c:0i?sort=price&order=asc which is supposed to work on Chrome Driver but on Geckodriver gives a cyclic object exception.

Anyone was able to make it work on firefox geckodriver and could share their code?

```
def expandShadowElement(self,element):
    shadowRoot = self.driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', element)
    return shadowRoot

root1 = self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name('makalu-app')
shadowRoot1 = self.expandShadowElement(root1)
```

Comment: what are you trying to access within?

Comment: just trying to access that root for now but it gives a cyclyc object error

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a solution but more a workaround. The Gekodriver doesn't seem to support shadow DOM as far as I can tell, but getting to an element is possible. The shadowRoot does not return a webelement, so you have get a little deeper.

```js
shadowRoot = self.driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot.firstChild', element)
```

It's not perfect, but you can then use that element as normal.

Comment: Just a note, you may get <style> or other unwanted elements with this method. You might need one of `firstChildElement` or `lastChildElement` instead of `firstChild`. Or you may need to get all children with `children` then loop through to find the one you want somehow (I don't know how to do this, just an idea).